# UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x1623fb680>

Tags: python

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
import matplotlib as plt
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import keras.utils as image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

train = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1/255)
validation = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1/255)
train_dataset = train.flow_from_directory('family/train/', target_size = (500,500), batch_size = 3 ,class_mode = 'binary')
validation_dataset = validation.flow_from_directory('family/validate/', target_size = (500,500), batch_size = 3 ,class_mode = 'binary')
train_dataset.class_indices
train_dataset.classes

from tensorflow.keras import layers , models
model=models.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Conv2D(16,(3,3),activation='relu', input_shape=(500,500,3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation = 'relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation = 'relu'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',optimizer = RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001), metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_dataset, steps_per_epoch = 3, epochs=30,validation_data=validation_dataset)

img = image.load_img("family/testing//test1.jpg")
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()

X= image.img_to_array(img)
X=np.expand_dims(X,axis=0)
images = np.vstack([X])
val=model.predict(images)
if val == 1 :
    print(" one")
if val == 2 :

    print(" two")
```

> Found 10 images belonging to 3 classes.
> Found 10 images belonging to 3 classes.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnidentifiedImageError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/5m/ybwkn1396vd8_rzf_7gpcv9c0000gq/T/ipykernel_7121/2750052911.py in <module>
     35 
     36 model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',optimizer = RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001), metrics = ['accuracy'])
---> 37 model.fit(train_dataset, steps_per_epoch = 3, epochs=30,validation_data=validation_dataset)
     38 
     39 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71         finally:
     72             del filtered_tb

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode, formats)
   3145     for message in accept_warnings:
   3146         warnings.warn(message)
-> 3147     raise UnidentifiedImageError(
   3148         "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)
   3149     )

UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x1623fb680>
```

The model stops at the `model.fit`
It show me the above error I don't know why it is an image classifier. Inside the family folder there is a folder called train and validate.

Comment: Could you please provide an schema  of your train and validation directory (or a screenshot) so we can help you.

Comment: my data consist of jpg images of 500 by 500 pixles.
I have the main folder called family. inside it there is three folders: train, validate and test. inside the train and validate there is two subfolders called lets say A and B.
@Cuartero

Comment: Have you tried to read all images with PIL before using `flow_from_directory`? Maybe there is one corrupted image in your dataset.

Comment: how to do that please ?